# Unable to connect to my local MAMP Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, http, port, mamp

I am having trouble connecting to my wordpress site I created locally. The site is a duplicate of the live site, and I using the downloaded files and exported database. However, when I attempt to access I experience the following error:
[image]

My Mamp instances seems to be running correctly:
[image]

and I'm running the following ports:
[image]

What am I missing here? I have another local site running on the same instance and it fires up just fine. Most of the related answers online reference a dns problem, but I don't see how that would affect a locally run site.

Note: adding :80 to the end of the url does cause a 404 to be returned, so perhaps part of the problem is the port?

Something is forcing https and I have not been able to figure out what it is. I commented out the following lines that whee present in wp-config:

````
//define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);```

and updated the following. to http:

```define('WP_HOME','http://localhost/sitename');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/sitename');```

I also updated .htaccess to the following per this post: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/221850/stop-wordpress-from-using-https-and-just-use-http

```# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress```

None of this so far has prevented the https redirect (or setting?). What is weird is I have another local wordpress site on this same instance of mamp and I am not experiencing the problem with it
````

Comment: did you change the URLs of the exported database in the options table? You will also need to change the wp-config.php file and update the database details to make sure it connecting to your localhost db

Comment: here is what I have it set to: `define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');`

Comment: Thats correct but you will also need to update the user name and password as MAMP has its own.. I believe the default username is root and password is empty... You may have to create one in order to get wordpress to work.

Comment: I created a new user name and password, updated wp-config to reflect, but still no luck. I did notice that the browser seems to be forcing https, even those I have define('FORCE_SSL', false); - could that be causing any issue?

Comment: that will definitely be causing an issue as you have no certificate for localhost. 
access phpMyAdmin via the MAMP page and then check your wordpress URL in the options table. 
Make sure its set to localhost.
You could also try commenting out everything in your root .htaccess file found in htdocs to see if theres something in there forcing the redirect

Comment: in wp_options, both home and site url are set to http://localhost/sitename. there was not a .htaccess file, so I downloaded and installed the live one, but I still get the same result of being directed to https

Comment: I have confirmed the domain references in the db in the wp_options table of siteurl and home are both set to http and not https. I have tried reinstalling the .htaccess file and removing it's contents. I've also removed a couple of caching plugins that I had downloaded from the live site. still no luck

Comment: is the browser still trying to force HTTPs? when you manually change the URL to http: does it force straight back to https? Can you go to chrome://net-internals/#dns and press the "Clear host cache" button

Comment: it still is. I tried the chrome location and cleared host cache but no luck